# subset of a database using SUM

Tags: subset

```
rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT Class1_predicted, Class2_predicted, Class3_predicted, Class_predicted"
+  SUM(PROFIT_LOSS) AS "Total Profit",
+ "FROM xxxxxx "
+ "WHERE CLASS1_PREDICTED = curr_class1_predicted, CLASS2_PREDICTED = curr_class2_predicted, CLASS3_PREDICTED = curr_class3_predicted, CLASS_PREDICTED = curr_class_predicted,"
+ "PROFIT_LOSS >= 0,"
+ "GROUP BY Class1_predicted, Class2_predicted, Class3_predicted,Class_predicted");

rs.next(); 

int recordCount = rs.getInt(1);

myConsole.getOut().println("Number of records in subset of table xxxxx where P/L >= 0: " + recordCount);
```

I am getting an error on the AS in the second line ?
Not sure how to correct ?

Bob M

Answer (score 0):

You should put the whole query in a String.

It seems like here you are not actually quoting the expression:

```
+  SUM(PROFIT_LOSS) AS "Total Profit",
```

It should be something like this:

```
+  "SUM(PROFIT_LOSS) AS Total_Profit,"
```